# MySQL - Count call answered within certain ranges 0 to 10 sec, group by count

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, range, intervals

I need to count call answered within certain ranges 0 to 10 sec, 0 to 20 sec, etc. The count will increase while the delta will be the different count between the current and the next. The % will be the current count / the final count total.

Here is the sqlfiddle that you can use with data for testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/803d2/2

Sample table of callsdetails:

```
+-----+----------------+----------+----------+---------------+
| id  | callid         | callerno | duration | status        |
+-----+----------------+----------+----------+---------------+
| 634 | 1479097551.228 | 1000     |        2 | complete      |
| 635 | 1479102518.248 | 1000     |       12 | complete      |
+-----+----------------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Ranges                 | Count    | Delta    |    %     | 
+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Between 0 to 10 secs   |       44 | +44      |  84.62 % |
| Between 0 to 20 secs   |       48 | +4       |  92.31 % |
| Between 0 to 30 secs   |       50 | +2       |  96.15 % |
| Between 0 to 40 secs   |       51 | +1       |  98.08 % |
| Between 0 to 50 secs   |       51 | +0       |  98.08 % |
| Between 0 to 60 secs   |       51 | +0       |  98.08 % |
| Between 0 to 70 secs   |       51 | +0       |  98.08 % |
| Between 0 to 80 secs   |       52 | +1       | 100.00 % |
| Between 0 to 90 secs   |       52 | +0       | 100.00 % |
| Between 0 to 100+ secs |       52 | +0       | 100.00 % |
+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
Total                            52
```

What I am able to create now is below query, if you can help to provide better solution, please advice. The problem that I face now is (Priority) I am not able to get the count and (secondary) the final count total (52) for the %, now I manually put in the final count total (52). Please help.

```
SELECT Ranges,Delta,ROUND(Delta/52*100,2) AS '%'
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    (
        IF(duration<=10,'10',IF(duration<=20,'20',IF(duration<=30,'30',
        IF(duration<=40,'40',IF(duration<=50,'50',
        IF(duration<=60,'60',IF(duration<=70,'70',IF(duration<=80,
        '80',IF(duration<=90,'90','100+')))))))))) 
        AS Ranges,COUNT(duration) AS Delta
        FROM callsdetails
        GROUP BY Ranges
    ) a
GROUP BY Ranges;
```

Current Result:

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| Ranges | Delta | %     |
+--------+-------+-------+
| 10     |    44 | 84.62 |
| 20     |     4 |  7.69 |
| 30     |     2 |  3.85 |
| 40     |     1 |  1.92 |
| 80     |     1 |  1.92 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

===========================================================================

Thanks to Etsa for helping me solved above problem which is the total of all calls, I might need help again now with addition of grouping per queue name. It's the same formula with above but now it must be split or group per queue name.

Here is the sqlfiddle that you can use with data for testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efe11b/2

Expected Result:

```
+---------+------+-----------+-------+--------+
| QUEUE   | RAN  | TOT_COUNT | DELTA | %      |
+---------+------+-----------+-------+--------+
| sales   | 10   |         6 |     6 | 100.00 |
| sales   | 20   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| sales   | 30   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| sales   | 40   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| sales   | 50   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| sales   | 60   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| sales   | 70   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| sales   | 80   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| sales   | 90   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| sales   | 100+ |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| enquiry | 10   |        32 |    32 |  80.00 |
| enquiry | 20   |        36 |     4 |  90.00 |
| enquiry | 30   |        38 |     2 |  95.00 |
| enquiry | 40   |        39 |     1 |  97.50 |
| enquiry | 50   |        39 |     0 |  97.50 |
| enquiry | 60   |        39 |     0 |  97.50 |
| enquiry | 70   |        39 |     0 |  97.50 |
| enquiry | 80   |        40 |     1 | 100.00 |
| enquiry | 90   |        40 |     0 | 100.00 |
| enquiry | 100+ |        40 |     0 | 100.00 |
| others  | 10   |         6 |     6 | 100.00 |
| others  | 20   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| others  | 30   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| others  | 40   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| others  | 50   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| others  | 60   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| others  | 70   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| others  | 80   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| other   | 90   |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
| others  | 100+ |         6 |     0 | 100.00 |
+---------+------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Have you tried something?  SO is not a free software service.  Try to make an effort, post it in your question and then ask for help.  Moreover, I suggest to create a new question.

Comment: Hi Etsa, I'm really sorry for making it seems like I'm taking advantages of you. I have been trying many times modifying your code but the more I try the more the end result shown are wrong. I'm really sorry for disturbing you as I not quite familiar with this and hoping to get help from you. I'm really sorry and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be this (using variable to obtain cumulative sum, and using a JOIN with all the intervals.  At last I added a JOIN with SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain 52):

```
SELECT RAN, TOT_COUNT, DELTA, ROUND(TOT_COUNT/E.TOT*100,2) AS '%'
FROM (SELECT B.RAN, a.Ranges, COALESCE(a.Delta,0) AS DELTA
      , @r:=@r+COALESCE(a.Delta,0) AS TOT_COUNT
      FROM (SELECT (
                    IF(duration<=10,'10',IF(duration<=20,'20',IF(duration<=30,'30',
                    IF(duration<=40,'40',IF(duration<=50,'50',
                    IF(duration<=60,'60',IF(duration<=70,'70',IF(duration<=80,
                    '80',IF(duration<=90,'90','100+')))))))))) 
                    AS Ranges,COUNT(duration) AS Delta
            FROM callsdetails C
            GROUP BY Ranges) A
        RIGHT JOIN (SELECT '10' AS RAN, 1 AS ORD UNION ALL SELECT '20', 2 AS ORD UNION ALL SELECT '30', 3
                UNION ALL SELECT '40', 4 UNION ALL SELECT '50', 5 UNION ALL SELECT '60',6 UNION ALL SELECT '70',7 
                UNION ALL SELECT '80',8 UNION ALL SELECT '90',9 UNION ALL SELECT '100+',10) B ON A.Ranges=B.RAN
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r:=0) T
        ORDER BY ORD
      ) D
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOT FROM callsdetails) E 
;
```

Output:

```
RAN TOT_COUNT   DELTA  %
10      44      44  84.62
20      48       4  92.31
30      50       2  96.15
40      51       1  98.08
50      51       0  98.08
60      51       0  98.08
70      51       0  98.08
80      52       1  100
90      52       0  100
100+    52       0  100
```

**Updated (new request in question).**

```
SELECT queueALL, RAN, TOT_COUNT, DELTA, ROUND(TOT_COUNT/D.TOT*100,2) AS '%'
FROM (
     SELECT B.queueALL, B.RAN, a.Ranges, COALESCE(a.Delta,0) AS DELTA, B.TOT
      , CASE WHEN queueALL=@q THEN @r:=@r+COALESCE(a.Delta,0) ELSE @r:=COALESCE(a.Delta,0) END AS TOT_COUNT
      , @q:=queueALL 
      , ORD
      FROM (SELECT queuename
             , CASE WHEN duration DIV 10.0001+1<=9 THEN CAST((duration DIV 10.0001+1)*10 AS CHAR) 
               ELSE '100+' END AS Ranges
             , COUNT(duration) AS Delta
            FROM callsdetails C
            GROUP BY queuename, Ranges) A
      RIGHT JOIN (SELECT B2.queuename AS queueALL, B2.TOT, B1.RAN, B1.ORD
                  FROM
                     (SELECT queuename, COUNT(*) AS TOT FROM callsdetails GROUP BY queuename) B2
                      CROSS JOIN (SELECT '10' AS RAN,1 AS ORD UNION ALL SELECT '20',2 AS ORD UNION ALL SELECT '30',3
                            UNION ALL SELECT '40',4 UNION ALL SELECT '50',5 UNION ALL SELECT '60',6 UNION ALL SELECT '70',7 
                            UNION ALL SELECT '80',8 UNION ALL SELECT '90',9 UNION ALL SELECT '100+',10)B1 ) B ON A.Ranges=B.RAN AND A.queuename = B.queueALL
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r:=0, @q:='') T
      ORDER BY queueALL, ORD) D
 ORDER BY queueALL, ORD
```

;

Output:

```
+----------+------+-----------+-------+------+
| queueALL | RAN  | TOT_COUNT | DELTA |  %   |
+----------+------+-----------+-------+------+
| enquiry  | 10   |        32 |    32 |   80 |
| enquiry  | 20   |        36 |     4 |   90 |
| enquiry  | 30   |        38 |     2 |   95 |
| enquiry  | 40   |        39 |     1 | 97.5 |
| enquiry  | 50   |        39 |     0 | 97.5 |
| enquiry  | 60   |        39 |     0 | 97.5 |
| enquiry  | 70   |        39 |     0 | 97.5 |
| enquiry  | 80   |        40 |     1 |  100 |
| enquiry  | 90   |        40 |     0 |  100 |
| enquiry  | 100+ |        40 |     0 |  100 |
| others   | 10   |         6 |     6 |  100 |
| others   | 20   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| others   | 30   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| others   | 40   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| others   | 50   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| others   | 60   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| others   | 70   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| others   | 80   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| others   | 90   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| others   | 100+ |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| sales    | 10   |         6 |     6 |  100 |
| sales    | 20   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| sales    | 30   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| sales    | 40   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| sales    | 50   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| sales    | 60   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| sales    | 70   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| sales    | 80   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| sales    | 90   |         6 |     0 |  100 |
| sales    | 100+ |         6 |     0 |  100 |
+----------+------+-----------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Hi Etsa, Thank you very much for your solution, I have been having this problem for quite some time, really appreciate your help. (^_^)

Comment: Hi Etsa, I have new issue that will need for your help. Last time you have help me solved above problem which is the total of all calls, I will need help again now with addition of grouping per queue name. It's the same formula with above but now it must be split or group per queue name. Please see above for the expected result.

Here is the sqlfiddle that you can use with data for testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efe11b/2

Comment: @DarkSilver    New version added, which include queuename.

Comment: Wooww you are so good at it, really thank you very very very much for your help. I will study and learn from your code. (^_^)